# How to save BLOB data type image

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store an image using BLOB data type in my filed in MYSQL database but when I hit Apply button, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1105: Parameter of prepared statement which is set through mysql_send_long_data() is longer than 'max_long_data_size' bytes
```

I will very much appreciate any inputs.

Comment: It's generally not a good solution to store images directly in the database. Why would you do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in xampp that 'my'(configuration file) location is "xampp\mysql\bin\" see in bin if you get that file there. and you try to use longblob instead of blob. longblob can store more data than blob.

**edit:** you can store image path (ie: ../image1.jpg) in database instead of storing image into database. storing image in database may cause problem and even its not impossible to crash database.

Comment: thts sounds like a good idea.let me try it. I hope it doesnt give me size issues

Answer (score 1):

The default value for max_long_data_size is 1048576 - is your picture bigger than that? If it is, you'll want to increase the value in your /etc/my.cnf file.

Comment: Where is this /etc/my.cnf file? I am fairly new to this so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I am using MYSQL, so can you please direct me on how to access the file you mentioned and how you can increase the size?